# I have created an SIP domain in Twilio. How do we configure a Polycom IP phone with the twilio settings?

Tags: twilio, sip, amazon-connect

I have setup a contact center using Amazon Connect. However, I now want to transfer the agent calls from CCP to the desk phones (IP based). After initial research, I found that currently Amazon Connect does not provide SIP integration, but we can use something like Twilio to achieve this.

I'm new to Twilio and created an SIP domain. I need some help in setting up the deskphone (like what proxy and server addresses we use etc.,)

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio is a sip trunk, not a sip extension.  To use it with a phone, you need a pbx, like freepbx.